# Use Newton's Method to compute sqrt(x)

Tags: lisp, scheme, numerical-methods

Given the following task:

> Use Newton's method to compute the square root of a number.  Newton's
>   method involves successive approximation.  You start with a guess, and
>   then continue averaging successive guesses until you reach a
>   satisfactory level of precision.

I wrote the following (rough) solution in Scheme.  Can you help me make it better?

```
(define (abs x) ((if (< x 0) - +)  x))
(define (almost-equal x y delta) 
    (> delta (abs (- x y))))

(define (sqrt-prime x last-x)
  (let ((next-x (/ (+ x last-x) 2)))
        (if (almost-equal next-x x 0.000001) x
            (sqrt-prime next-x x))))

(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-prime x 1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sqrt-prime` function neither needs nor uses the `last-guess` argument.  It can be safely eliminated:

```
(define (sqrt-prime guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess x) guess
      (sqrt-prime (better-guess guess x) x)))
```

You may call the function thus:

```
(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-prime 1.0 x))
```

I feel that, other than this minor change, your program is succinct enough.

Comment: Good point.  I got some good feedback on (cuberoot ...) so I'm changing this quite a bit, but otherwise I'd definitely fix it - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is mentioned in R6RS, so I'm inclined to believe that you can treat it as a primitive.

---

The scheme convention is to end predicates with `?`, so that should really be `almost-equal?`